# How to calculate daily retention rate?

Tags: r

I'm new to R. Here is my data:

```
data
   id      date
1   1 2015/10/1
2   2 2015/10/1
3   3 2015/10/1
4   4 2015/10/1
5   5 2015/10/1
6   1 2015/10/2
7   3 2015/10/2
8   4 2015/10/2
9   6 2015/10/2
10  7 2015/10/2
11  1 2015/10/3
12  7 2015/10/3
13  3 2015/10/3
14  9 2015/10/3
15  1 2015/10/4
16 10 2015/10/4
17 11 2015/10/4
```

I want to calculate the retention rate for each day of the 'id'. The id may new or repeated every day. I want to treat everyday as the initial date and find next following day's retention rate for it.

So far I have tried...

```
oct1<-data[which(data$date =="2015/10/1"),]
oct2<-data[which(data$date == "2015/10/2"),]
oct3<-data[which(data$date == "2015/10/3"),]
oct4<-data[which(data$date == "2015/10/4"),]

union_a1<-oct1$id[which(oct1$id%in%oct2$id)]
union_a2<- oct1$id[which(oct1$id%in%oct3$id)]
union_a3<- oct1$id[which(oct1$id%in%oct4$id)]

per_a1=length(union_a1)/length(oct1$id)
per_a2=length(union_a2)/length(oct1$id)
per_a2=length(union_a3)/length(oct1$id)

union_b1<-oct2$id[which(oct2$id%in%oct3$id)]
union_b2<-oct2$id[which(oct2$id%in%oct4$id)]

per_b1<-length(union_b1)/length(oct2$id)
per_b2<- length(union_b2)/length(oct2$id)

union_c1<-oct3$id[which(oct3$id%in%oct4$id)]
per_c1<-length(union_c1)/length(oct3$id)
per_a1
# [1] 0.6
per_a2
# [1] 0.4
per_a3
# [1] 0.2
per_b1
# [1] 0.6
per_b2
# [1] 0.2
per_c1
# [1] 0.25
```

Could anyone help me to write a `for` loop to solve this question? I think the `for` loop is easy for counting each day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a fan of for-loops, so I'm suggesting an alternative approach using `dplyr` (data manipulation) and `lubridate` (to deal with dates).
This process uses grouping and all possible dates combinations of interest to replace a for-loop. Note that I'm taking into account what you mention in your comments below : that you want to find the retention rate based on the new users you have for a specific day.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

data = read.table(text="   id      date
                  1   1 2015/10/1
                  2   2 2015/10/1
                  3   3 2015/10/1
                  4   4 2015/10/1
                  5   5 2015/10/1
                  6   1 2015/10/2
                  7   3 2015/10/2
                  8   4 2015/10/2
                  9   6 2015/10/2
                  10  7 2015/10/2
                  11  1 2015/10/3
                  12  7 2015/10/3
                  13  3 2015/10/3
                  14  9 2015/10/3
                  15  1 2015/10/4
                  16 10 2015/10/4
                  17 11 2015/10/4")

## update your date column to date object 
data$date = ymd(data$date)


expand.grid(date1 = unique(data$date),                             ## create all combinations between dates
            date2 = unique(data$date)) %>%
  filter(date1 < date2) %>%                                        ## keep only cases where 2nd date is after 1st date
  group_by(date1, date2) %>%                                       ## for each combination of dates
  do({ids_1 = setdiff(unique(data[data$date == ymd(.$date1),]$id), ## get new ids in date1 (they showed up first time at this date)
                      unique(data[data$date < ymd(.$date1),]$id))           
  N_ids_1 = length(ids_1)                                          ## count how many ids you have
  ids_2 = unique(data[data$date == ymd(.$date2),]$id)              ## get ids from date2
  N_ids_2 = length(intersect(ids_2, ids_1))                        ## count how many ids exist in previous dataset
  data.frame(Prc = N_ids_2/N_ids_1)}) %>%                          ## calculate the percentage          
  ungroup()

#        date1      date2   Prc
#       (time)     (time) (dbl)
# 1 2015-10-01 2015-10-02   0.6
# 2 2015-10-01 2015-10-03   0.4
# 3 2015-10-01 2015-10-04   0.2
# 4 2015-10-02 2015-10-03   0.5
# 5 2015-10-02 2015-10-04   0.0
# 6 2015-10-03 2015-10-04   0.0
```

Comment: thank you so much ~the package of dplyr is really useful. Actually my data of time has the format of  yyyy-mm-dd, I know you change the yyyy/mm/dd to yyyy-mm-dd at first. I don't know how to make a change in this question. it seems that  do({dt1 = data[data$date == ymd(.$date1),] doesn't work for yyyy-mm-dd format..

Comment: Is it possible to do a `dput(data)` and post the output here so I can see what format you have?

Comment: I make it out ,but my data is too long, it just shows up for ten lines. could you tell me how could see the result in the console or how could i save the result?

Comment: For 10 first rows is good enough to see the format. Just copy and paste the output when you run the command `dput` under your question. Sould be something like `structure(list(...........`

Comment: the date of the data has the format like 2015-10-5, i don't know why when I put it onto here, it changes. do i still need ymd format if i have the date showed like 2015-10-5. One more place i'm confused is that what is the meaning of dot in the ymd(.$date1)....Thank you so much always!

Comment: I mean my result is like 21*3 data frame , but the r console only shows up for ten lines , the entire row i couldn't see...

Comment: Not sure about the date question. Try to run the same process without the `ymd` command and see if it works. The `.` means "current dataset". So, `.$date1` means "from whatever dataset I have at that time in my pipelined process get the column `date1`".

Comment: i use another large data which comes out the 30 rows of the retention rate. but the r console only prints  out for ten rows, how could i see all the retention rate?

Comment: Try to use `%>% print(n=nrow(.))` in the end. It should work.

Comment: I have another concern， the ids of second date may be exist on previous day, we will need to delete them and form a second date ids

Comment: so the first day retention rate is right. But the next days are wrong. for example, only id6 and id7 could be consider as the original data set for  10/2,and the id 7 exist on 10/3, so the retention rate of one day for oct2 is 1/2=0.5. Do you know what i mean? I really need your help. I'm so sorry i calculate wrong and make a wrong example in previous .

Comment: It makes sense. You'll need to find only the new users of each date and check how many of them come the next day, right? I'll try to fix the code and update my answer. Id it possible to update your example so people don't get confused when they read that post?

Comment: Thanks!! The codes are right ! I will fix my question later.

Comment: I just post another question, Could you help me solve that one? Really need your help.

Comment: I'll check soon. I think someone else will be faster and solve it! :-)